# Apply formula to get Numpy matrix efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I am trying to parse through 2 vectors, and fill a matrix based on a formula. This is the way I am doing it, it is highly inefficient.

```
import numpy as np

list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list2 = [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]

array1 = np.array(list1)
array2 = np.array(list2)

columns = len(list1)
rows = len(list2)

matrix = np.zeros((rows, columns))

for column in range(0, columns):
    for row in range(2*column, rows):
        matrix[row, column] = round(10 * (array2[row] - array1[column]), 0)

print(matrix)
```

The output should be

```
[[190.   0.   0.   0.]
 [290.   0.   0.   0.]
 [390. 380.   0.   0.]
 [490. 480.   0.   0.]
 [590. 580. 570.   0.]
 [690. 680. 670.   0.]
 [790. 780. 770. 760.]
 [890. 880. 870. 860.]]
```

This is an example, the real arrays are large.
How can I use numpy built-in code to do this in the most efficient and optimized way?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
list1 = list(range(1,50))
list2 = list(range(20,1000,10))
array1 = np.array(list1)
array2 = np.array(list2)

columns = len(list1)
rows = len(list2)

# yours
def f():
    matrix = np.zeros((rows, columns))
    for column in range(0, columns):
        for row in range(2*column, rows):
            matrix[row, column] = round(10 * (array2[row] - array1[column]), 0)
    return matrix

def g():
    col, row = np.meshgrid(np.arange(columns), np.arange(rows))
    mask = row>=2*col
    matrix = np.where(mask, np.round(10*(array2[:,None] - array1), 0), 0)
    return matrix

col, row = np.meshgrid(np.arange(columns), np.arange(rows))
mask = row>=2*col
def h():
    matrix = np.where(mask, np.round(10*(array2[:,None] - array1), 0), 0)
    return matrix


import timeit

%timeit f()
# 3.18 ms ± 246 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit g()
# 64.7 µs ± 1.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit h()
# 21.7 µs ± 1.69 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

`f`, `g` and `h` are comparable on your small array but then `g` and `h` get much faster on bigger ones.

`h` is a further optimization on `g` if you need to do the same sort of computation several times on same size lists, since you can compute your mask only once...

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is a huge improvement on time. Before It would take like 20 seconds to compute the real data, now its less than 1 sec.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is much more detailed, but I still wanted to present this concise solution, easier to understand. It relies on the mathematical formulation of your problem, since you only want to substract two 1D-arrays at each coordinate of your matrix, an easy way to do so is to "transform" your 1D-arrays into well written 2D ones with `np.tile`, which you then only have to substract.

Finally, to select only the coordinates verifying `row >= 2*column`, you can create a boolean array `(y >= 2*x)`, which when multiplied by your previous array `C`, will put to 0 all coordinates that do not check this condition.

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
b = np.array([20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90])
n = len(a)
m = len(b)

A = np.tile(a, (m,1))
B = np.tile(b, (n,1)).T

'''
At this point, we have :
A = [[1 2 3 4]
     [1 2 3 4]
     [1 2 3 4]
     [1 2 3 4]
     [1 2 3 4]
     [1 2 3 4]
     [1 2 3 4]
     [1 2 3 4]]
and
B = [[20 20 20 20]
     [30 30 30 30]
     [40 40 40 40]
     [50 50 50 50]
     [60 60 60 60]
     [70 70 70 70]
     [80 80 80 80]
     [90 90 90 90]]

so by definition matrix is exactly 10 * (B-A) ! 
It is really easy to see by writting down a bit of maths, 
since matrix[i,j] = 10 * (b[i] - a[j]).
'''

C = np.round(10*(B-A), 0)

x,y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(n), np.arange(m))

matrix = C * (y >= 2*x)
```

Comment: Why use  separate ways to make the 2d arrays, `tile` and `meshgrid`?  Can't you use the same method twice?  How about the `sparse` version of meshgrid?  Or `broadcasting`?

Comment: This was the easiest solution that came to my mind when doing this (in fact, I saw the condition on rows and columns only after finishing the array `C`), and I haven't thought of anything else to produce a cleaner result. But if you have a better solution, feel free to share it ! It could benefit me as well :)